# Single page controller not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, concrete5-5.7

So I have created a single page as subpage at:
`/application/single_pages/leden/mijnaccount.php`

Added it at the single pages list in dashboard.
The page is working fine.

But when I add a controller at:
`/application/controllers/single_page/leden/mijnaccount.php`

With the following contents to test:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller\SinglePage;
use Concrete\Core\Page\Controller\PageController;

class Mijnaccount extends PageController
{
    public function on_start()
    {
        exit('Started');
    }

    public function view()
    {
        exit('View');
    }

    public function on_before_render()
    {
        exit('Before render');
    }
}
```

None of those `exit()` functions get called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be to add the subfolder to the namespace:

```
namespace Application\Controller\SinglePage;
```

Becomes:

```
namespace Application\Controller\SinglePage\Leden;
```